# How to convert the stream generated by wkhmtlopdf in node to base64 string without converting the stream to buffer using AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I have a requirement where I need to convert HTML to pdf using wkhtmltopdf using node js and AWS Lambda. So we are using nodejs wrappper for wkhtmltopdf (nodejs-wkhtmltopdf.
So far so good, we are successful in converting the HTML to pdf but the challenges which we are facing is when we have to return the pdf to the client-side.
In express, we are aware that we can pipe the stream to the response object.

```
stream = wkhtmtopdf(compiledData).pipe(res)
```

My question is how to do the same in AWS Lambda.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

simple.
use express as a layer in lambda and import it in the code of nodejs.
then you can use the same way of pipe the stream to the response.

layers
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html